# Make UIViewController outside Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i have a question for you. I'm working on this app that has a walkthrough/tutorial screens and also login ones. On each of this screens there is a button to skip this part and go directly to use the app, without completing the registration (you know, so that people can test it before signing-in).

[image: Controllers as seen in the Storyboard]

As you can see i'm using Storyboards. The NowPlaying04 ViewController is actually the app itself. Obviously, when the user will be a registered one, i should also be able to jump right back to that screen, skipping the walkthrough and signin process.

The first question is: how is the best way to structure this?

The second quesion is: how i can make a ViewController outside that Navigation controller. Cause as you can see now, the NowPlaying04 ViewController inherits the top navigation bar. Which is a thing that i don't want. I don't need that.

I hope that you have understood my question. I'll appreciate any help. Programmatically or by dragging stuff around, i'm ok with all the solutions. The important thing is that it works correctly! :-)

Comment: To check that user has signed use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults],depending on it use different rootviewcontroller and skip all your sign vc.

Comment: @НаильГалиаскаров Ok. Tell me more about this! For now i have set a BOOL value (just to test this) in the AppDelegate: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL userLoggedIn = NO;
    if (userLoggedIn) {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[NowPlaying04 alloc] init];
    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[Walkthrough01 alloc] init];
    }}` but when i run this with userLoggedIn set to NO, i just get a black screen..no UI..no NavigationController topbar. Just Status bar and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I maybe found a solution to this issue, using the AppDelegate.m. If you're using Storyboards, you don't need to import in the AppDelegate.h the ViewController classes, cause you're referencing them using StoryboardID. It looks something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL userLoggedIn = NO;
    if (userLoggedIn) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NowPlaying04"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
    } else {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Start00"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to set identifiers on the view controllers through the InterfaceBuilder/Storyboard properties. Setting a different value to the BOOL variable userLoggedIn the app loads with the relative rootViewController.

Now the Storyboard looks like this:

[image: Storyboard after edit]

Which is much more organized. isInitialViewController is flagged on the NowPlaying04 screen. But the AppDelegate decides if to go to it or rather switch to the NavigationController (with ID Start00), based on the isLoggedIn BOOL variable.

Thanks to @НаильГалиаскаров for idea of using different rootViewControllers.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to hide the navigation bar, but this code to your ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

To jump to a specific ViewController you can use this code:

```
NSInteger index = -1;
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
for(int i=0 ; i<arr.count ; i++)
{
    if([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"Your_ViewController_Class_Name")])
    {
        index = i;
    }
}
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i know i can hide the navigation bar, i have done it also on some of the other screens (even if in Storyboard they show up anyway). About the jump to a specific view controller, how do you suggest i do that. Cause i'm thinking to check if user is logged in on the AppDelegate and then jump to the right ViewController! Is this reasonable?

Comment: google NSUserDefaults, there you can save data like a bool. so you can save the bool registered und you can read it. Then you just need if(registered){...jump to viewcontroller...}. Even if the app was closed, the iOS Device was restarted, your bool value is still accessable.

Comment: Ok. But the question is: where should i check that NSUserDefault saved 'registered' BOOL value? On the AppDelegate, right?

Comment: I think you need a main viewcontroller, a viewcontroller before the walkthrough 01 viewcontroller. In this main viewcontroller you can check if the user needs to go to this viewcontroller or if the user can directly enter the "now enter" view controller. In your storyboard picture the walkthrough viewcontroller is the first viewcontroller the user can see, but some users dont need that. I think you need to think about that again. I hope this is useful for you

Comment: I would like to have like two separate flows and set rootViewController from the AppDelegate (if user is logged in > set NowPlaying04 as rootViewController; if user is not logged in > set Walkthrough01 as rootViewController, register user and then jump to the NowPlaying04 VC). This will be the best solution. Also to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

You can set the skip button's implementation to navigate you to the NowPlaying04 view controller.

```
        UIButton* skipButton    =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [skipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(skip) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)skip
{
    NowPlaying04* nowPlayingController  =   [[NowPlaying04 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nowPlayingController animated:YES];
}
```

Question 2:

Set the navigation bar hidden in NowPlaying04.
In the init method or viewWillAppear method of NowPlaying04, just set the navigationbar hidden.

```
navBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable too! Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: When i try this i get: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: May i know where the error comes? For the first question or the second question? Can you show some piece of code?

Comment: I actually used this, but a little workaround cause i'm using storyboards. Check it out. `-(void)skip
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Walkthrough04"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}` Makes a pretty good sence and works good! So thank you for the idea! I use this cause i decided to have 2 different rootViewControllers, not under the same navVC as they were before..that's why I was getting that error i guess.

Answer (score 1):

@user1447316, I am glad that you liked my idea. However, I would rather use **standarduserdefaults** instead of local variable userLoggedIn. Saving this way is great when you want to save small amounts of data which you need even after user closed your app such as High Scores, Login Information, and program state.

You can save data once user logged from any place in your application by:

```
NSNumber *userLoggedIn = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userLoggedIn forKey:@"log"];
```

And then you can check by retrieving:

```
  NSNumber *userLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"log"];
  if ([userLoggedIn boolValue]){
         //user logged
  }
```

e.x. This nice technique will allow you even to detect your first launch and show to user some tutorial :)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I really appreciate all the recieved support. I'll use this tecnique for sure!

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I would present the register VCs as a modal.

```
if (!registered){
     [nowPlaying04  presentViewController:registrationNav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```