# Setter in NSString iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, setter, getter

hi i am new to ios dev ,I am trying to set a value for nsstring from delegate class and access from other class ,the value i get is null.i dont know what mistake i am doing?

```
//token class header file
@interface TokenClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *tokenValue;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *tokenValue;

//token class main file
@implementation TokenClass
@synthesize tokenValue;
@end

//App Delegate
TokenClass *token = [[TokenClass alloc]init];
[token setTokenValue:@"as"];
```

when i access tokenvalue in some other classs i get null value.
can any one point me what mistake i am doing?Am i using @ property correctly?

Comment: how do you access tokenvalue property in another class show its code.

Comment: TokenClass *token = [[TokenClass alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"token here is %@",token.tokenValue);

Comment: They are different instances. Create some shared instance of TokenClass to retrieve it from any class.

Comment: You also need to learn from a more up-to-date tutorial. Modern Objective-C precludes the need to explicitly declare a property's ivar and the `@synthesize` line.

Comment: Neil,can u post some link or code to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Singleton class to expose variables or objects to the entire project or create global variables. Create sharedInstance of TokenClass class and create property which can be accessed anywhere

in your `.h` file

```
//token class header file
@interface TokenClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *tokenValue;

//create static method 
+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

in `.m` file

```
#import "TokenClass.h"

@implementation TokenClass


#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static TokenClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      tokenValue = [[NSString alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

now in your appDelegate

```
#import TokenClass.h

@implementation AppDelegate

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

 [TokenClass sharedInstance] setTokenValue:@"as"];
```

in any class you can get value using

```
NSLog(@"tokenValue = %@", [[SingletonClass sharedInstance] tokenValue]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want:

**1.** Usually I am using `NSUserDefaults` to save small amount of data which I will need even the user closed the app. There are a lot of information how to use it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808413/make-uiviewcontroller-outside-navigation-controller/19815079#19815079) here.

**2.** In your UIViewController class (e.x. your rootViewController) create `@property`  which will hold your `TokenClass`. Then you will get `tokenValue` by `self.tokenClass.tokenValue`

**3.** The other way is create a singleton class which will be available during the whole run loop of your application. A Singleton candidate must satisfy three requirements:

1. controls concurrent access to a shared resource.
2. access to the resource will be requested from multiple, disparate
   parts of the system.
3. there can be only one object.

   `+(TokenClass*) sharedTokenClass {`

   ```
   static dispatch_once_t pred;
   static TokenClass *_sharedTokenClass = nil;


       dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
           _sharedTokenClass = [[TokenClass alloc] init];
       });
       return _sharedTokenClass;
   }
   ```

   You will use it it from any place you want by 
   `[TokenClass sharedTokenClass]tokenValue];`

If I were you, I would use the first variant.

**PS.** I *strongly* recommend you to read some memory management articles to get the point of object's lifecycle.