# Access methods from other classes - is this a legitimate way

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm pretty new to the whole coding scene and was trying to create a way of accessing similar methods from anywhere within my app. I created a class called `HelperMethods : NSObject`. I then defined all my helper methods like this: `+ (returnObject *) thisIsMyHelperMethodWithParameter:(object*)object;` and then created the method body in the implementation. I then put an `#import "HelperMethods.h"` in my app prefix file so I can access it wherever I like in the app. I then call `[HelperMethod thisIsMyHelperMethodWithParameter:];` from anywhere within the app. It works fine and I haven't had any problem, but is this a legitimate way of creating a central hub for useful methods?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: please check my answer in this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872720/setter-in-nsstring-ios/19872986#19872986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well better if you want to create the class which work as a central hub then create the singleton class and access anywhere fron the other class. The advantage of creating singleton class is that it shared single memory space. So that it will be less overhead, when accessed the methods and variable from other class.

Comment: So you're saying that it's better to create a singleton to stop multiple allocations, right? So every time I call `[DataModel doSomething];` I'm creating a new instance? If so, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes correct, if you make singleton it will be less memory overhead and it will create only single instance.